# tokenize an email using python

Tags: python, email, tokenize

I need to tokenize an email using python
Means, I need the headers, the text, each and everything to be stored in some different variable.
Currently I am trying to do it with this email class of python
Please let me know how to do it even if you know with email class

Thank you 
Regards,
Puneet

Comment: In what way do the supplied documentation and examples not help you?

Comment: I am trying to understand them for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the standard python library documentation for the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) package

Use  email.parser.Parser.parse function to return a email.message.Message object that has the headers in a dictionary like representation

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that. But I am just figuring about what to do with this obj.
I have extracted out payload, made an email generator, degenerator object till now